# Javascript performance optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, function, csv, optimization

I created the following js function

```
function csvDecode(csvRecordsList)
{
    var cel;
    var chk;
    var chkACB;
    var chkAF;
    var chkAMR;
    var chkAN;
    var csvField;
    var csvFieldLen;
    var csvFieldsList;
    var csvRow;
    var csvRowLen = csvRecordsList.length;
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var injectFragInTbody = function () {tblbody.replaceChild(frag, tblbody.firstElementChild);};
    var isFirstRec;
    var len;
    var newEmbtyRow;
    var objCells;
    var parReEx = new RegExp(myCsvParag, 'ig');
    var tblbody;
    var tblCount = 0;
    var tgtTblBodyID;

    for (csvRow = 0; csvRow < csvRowLen; csvRow++)
    {
        if (csvRecordsList[csvRow].startsWith(myTBodySep))
        {
            if (frag.childElementCount > 0)
            {
                injectFragInTbody();
            }
            tgtTblBodyID = csvRecordsList[csvRow].split(myTBodySep)[1];
            newEmbtyRow = getNewEmptyRow(tgtTblBodyID);
            objCells = newEmbtyRow.cells;
            len = newEmbtyRow.querySelectorAll('input')[0].parentNode.cellIndex; // Finds the cell index where is placed the first input (Check-box or button)

            tblbody = getElById(tgtTblBodyID);
            chkAF = toBool(tblbody.dataset.acceptfiles);
            chkACB = toBool(tblbody.dataset.acceptcheckboxes) ;
            chkAN = toBool(tblbody.dataset.acceptmultiplerows) ;
            tblCount++;
            continue;
        }

        csvRecordsList[csvRow] = csvRecordsList[csvRow].replace(parReEx, myInnerHTMLParag); // Replaces all the paragraph symbols ¶ used into the db.csv file with the tag <br> needed into the HTML content of table cells, this way will be possible to use line breaks into table cells
        csvFieldsList = csvRecordsList[csvRow].split(myEndOfFld);

        csvFieldLen = csvFieldsList.length;
        for (csvField = 0; csvField < csvFieldLen; csvField++)
        {
            cel = chkAN ? csvField + 1 : csvField;
            if (chkAF && cel === 1) {objCells[cel].innerHTML =  makeFileLink(csvFieldsList[csvField]);} 
            else if (chkACB && cel === len) {objCells[cel].firstChild.checked = toBool(csvFieldsList[csvField]);}
            else {objCells[cel].innerHTML = csvFieldsList[csvField];}
        }
        frag.appendChild(newEmbtyRow.cloneNode(true));
    }
    injectFragInTbody();

    var recNum = getElById(tgtTblBodyID).childElementCount;
    customizeHtmlTitle();
    return csvRow - tblCount + ' (di cui '+ recNum + ' record di documenti)';
}
```

More than 90% of records could contain file names that have to be processed by the following makeFileLink function:

```
function makeFileLink(fname)
{
    return ['<a href="', dirDocSan, fname, '" target="', previewWinName, '" title="Apri il file allegato: ', fname, '" >', fname, '</a>'].join('');
}
```

It aims to decode a record list from a special type of *.db.csv file (= a comma-separated values where commas are replaced by another symbol I hard-coded into the var myEndOfFld). (This special type of *.db.csv is created by another function I wrote and it is just a "text" file).

The record list to decode and append to HTML tables is passed to the function with its lone parameter: **(csvRecordsList)**.

Into the csv file is hosted data coming from more HTML tables.

Tables are different for number of rows and columns and for some other contained data type (which could be filenames, numbers, string, dates, checkbox values).

Some tables could be just 1 row, others accept more rows.

A row of data has the following basic structure:

```
data field content 1|data field content 2|data field content 3|etc...
```

Once decoded by my algorithm it will be rendered correctly into the HTML td element even if into a field there are more paragraphs. In fact the tag 
 will be added where is needed by the code:

```
csvRecordsList[csvRow].replace(par, myInnerHTMLParag)
```

that replaces all the char I choose to represent the paragraph symbol I have hard-coded into the variable `myCsvParag`.

Isn't possible to know at programming time the number of records to load in each table nor the number of records loaded from the CSV file, nor the number of fields of each record or what table field is going to contain data or will be empty: in the same record some fields could contain data others could be empty. Everything has to be discovered at runtime.

Into the special csv file each table is separated from the next by a row witch contains just a string with the following pattern: **myTBodySep = tablebodyid** where **myTBodySep = "targettbodydatatable"** that is just a hard coded string of my choice.
tablebodyid is just a placeholder that contains a string representing the id of the target table tbody element to insert new record in, for example: tBodyDataCars, tBodyDataAnimals... etc.

So when the first for loop finds into the csvRecordsList a string staring with the string into the variable **myTBodySep** it gets the tablebodyid from the same row: this will be the new tbodyid that has to be targeted for injecting next records in it

Each table is archived into the CSV file

The first for loop scan the csv record list from the file and the second for loop prepare what is needed to compile the targeted table with data.

The above code works well but it is a little bit slow: in fact to load into the HTML tables about 300 records from the CSV file it takes a bit more of 2.5 seconds on a computer with 2 GB ram and Pentium core 2 4300 dual-core at 1800 MHz but if I comment the row that update the DOM the function needs less than 0.1 sec. So IMHO the bottle neck is the fragment and DOM manipulating part of the code.

My aim and hope is to optimize the speed of the above code without losing functionalities.

Notice that I'm targeting just modern browsers and I don't care about others and non standards-compliant browsers... I feel sorry for them...

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

### Edit 16-02.2018

I don't know if it is useful but lastly I've noticed that if data is loaded from browser sessionstorage the load and rendering time is more or less halved. But strangely it is the exact same function that loads data from both file and sessionstorage.
I don't understand why of this different behavior considering that the data is exactly the same and in both cases is passed to a variable handled by the function itself before starting checking performance timing.

### Edit 18.02.2018

1. Number of rows is variable depending on the target table: from 1 to 1000 (could be even more in particular cases)
2. Number of columns depending on the target table: from 10 to 18-20

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you think the output HTML should be after this function runs? That might help me give you a better answer, rather than just trying to reverse-engineer what you have done here.

Comment: What does `injectFragInTbody` do? Are you sure you need it *inside* the `for` loop? Additional advice: try not using strings & `innerHTML` (use `document.createElement` and `node.appendChild` instead) to see if it makes a difference (it should).

Comment: @user3297291 the **injectFragInTbody** function replaces the empty row of the table with the block of rows contained into the fragment that contains data got from file (or from browser sessionstorage). It does that at every change of the targeted table and at the end of the loop for the last table.

Comment: @th3n3wguy no need for a sample: the code just get the data of the variable csvRecordsList (that could be a file content or a key value of the browser session storage content, doesn't matter) and inserts it into some html tables

Comment: As far as the JS, use the dev tools profiler and narrow down which things take the longest.  But also, DOM manipulation is a two-way street - reading from the DOM can have a significant impact depending on how many nodes your page has loaded, classes, etc.  You need to pay attention to things like - when the elements are replaced, have they moved or gotten bigger/smaller?  Styles and classes on that table/td's will also have a significant impact.  Tables are exempt as a layout boundary but the rendering inside can still be costly, especially if you have more than ~200 rows and lots of columns.

Comment: @user3297291 I used createElement and appendChild but in my computer it takes 10 secs: far longer than innerHTML approach (2 ~ 2.5 sec) so I restored the innerHTML approach (the above published version of the code)

Answer (score 5):

In fact, building the table using DOM manipulations are way slower than simple `innerHTML` update of the table element.

And if you tried to rewrite your code to prepare a html string and put it into the table's innerHTML you would see a significant performance boost.

Browsers are optimized to parse the `text/html` which they receive from the server as it's their main purpose. DOM manipulations via JS are secondary, so they are not so optimized.

I've made a simple benchmark for you.

Lets make a table 300x300 and fill 90000 cells with 'A'.
There are two functions.

The first one is **a simplified variant of your code** which uses `DOM methods`:

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table tbody');
var cells_in_row = 300, rows_total = 300;

var start = performance.now();
fill_table_1();
console.log('using DOM methods: ' + (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2) + 'ms');

table.innerHTML = '<tbody></tbody>';


function fill_table_1() {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var injectFragInTbody = function() {
    table.replaceChild(frag, table.firstElementChild)
  }

  var getNewEmptyRow = function() {
    var row = table.firstElementChild;
    if (!row) {
      row = table.insertRow(0);
      for (var c = 0; c < cells_in_row; c++) row.insertCell(c);
    }
    return row.cloneNode(true);
  }

  for (var r = 0; r < rows_total; r++) {
    var new_row = getNewEmptyRow();
    var cells = new_row.cells;
    for (var c = 0; c < cells_in_row; c++) cells[c].innerHTML = 'A';
    frag.appendChild(new_row.cloneNode(true));
  }
  injectFragInTbody();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

The second one prepares html string and put it into the table's `innerHTML`:

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table tbody');
var cells_in_row = 300, rows_total = 300;

var start = performance.now();
fill_table_2();
console.log('setting innerHTML: ' + (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2) + 'ms');

table.innerHTML = '<tbody></tbody>';

function fill_table_2() {// setting innerHTML
  var html = '';
  for (var r = 0; r < rows_total; r++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (var c = 0; c < cells_in_row; c++) html += '<td>A</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  table.innerHTML = html;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

I believe you'll come to some conclusions.

Comment: This benchmark is super misleading. Replace the repeated `innerHTML` set (parses for every cell!) with `textContent`, reorder the two attempts, and use a more normal row setup – you’ll end up with DOM reporting as faster. (That won’t be an accurate benchmark either – I’m just explaining why this one doesn’t show anything.) Try it on Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/7z2dLv2r/

Comment: Thanks Kosh. Wow! Results for me in Chrome: DOM 2345 ms and innerHTML 322 ms your test shows that innerHTML is faster more or less 7 times than DOM methods. I don't understand: everybody out there says that it's far better to use DOM method instead innerHTML because the DOM methods are faster. But the results here is exactly the opposite How is that possible? I'm really confused. And also I have to say that before I was using innerHTML myself and timing was 1.2 - 1.3 secs but now with DOM methods is slower. So I "can kind of confirm" your approach. But why others have so different experience?

Comment: @Ryan **setting innerHTML: 348.00ms
using DOM methods: 1141.00ms
true** It seems to me that Kosh has a point and his approach is not misleading at all, may be it can be optimized but it is an interesting point.

Comment: @willywonka: Did you try it on Firefox? Both are faster than Chrome’s innerHTML. But yes, it’s still misleading on Chrome because you can see the difference changed from 7× to 3× in a toy example.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for suggestion: results on ff **setting innerHTML: 234.54ms
using DOM methods: 277.45ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 223.81ms
using DOM methods: 257.80ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 224.49ms
using DOM methods: 252.23ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 232.85ms
using DOM methods: 270.35ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 224.15ms
using DOM methods: 260.73ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 218.59ms
using DOM methods: 254.74ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 223.58ms
using DOM methods: 269.07ms
true** **setting innerHTML: 217.38ms
using DOM methods: 253.65ms
true**

Comment: @willywonka: Refresh it a couple of times. The order will change, if you’re on the latest version. (A realistic implementation of the `innerHTML` version would also include HTML escaping, which is the main reason to use the DOM API – preventing vulnerabilities, not improving performance.)

Comment: @Ryan I have done some refreshes and copy-pasted results in the previous comment in ff: my conclusion is that innerHTML is faster a little bit in my ff. What about you? Can you copy-past some results please? (I'm using ff 58.0b4 (32 bit))

Comment: @willywonka: FF60: setting innerHTML: 76.00ms
using DOM methods: 68.00ms
true (again, though – meaningless and intended to show why you need a better benchmark, not that DOM is faster)

Comment: @Ryan thanks. In your case they have more or less similar performances. Maybe browser are going into the direction to optimize both innerHTML and DOM approaches. Also it seems to me that you have a better computer HW configuration that is about 3-4 times faster than mine. Anyway I feel lost.

Comment: @willywonka, in my benchmark I used the DOM methods which **you used in your code**. I believe you cannot replace `objCells[cel].innerHTML` with `objCells[cel].textContent` as you insert HTML. I tested **your code** not some DOM methods in general. And if you tried to rewrite your code to prepare a html string and put it into the table's innerHTML you would see a significant performance boost. Browsers are optimized to parse `text/html` they receive from the server as it's their main purpose. DOM manipulations via JS are secondary, so they are not so optimized.

Comment: I had similar experience and used the exact same approach as @KoshVery applied, and it worked like awesome, as the less you modify the DOM, the less processing it needs and you save up unnecessary CPU processing and GPU rendering.

Comment: @MunimMunna, thanks for supporting me. I had a similar issue too in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

I've got two thoughts for you.

1: If you want to know which parts of your code are (relatively) slow you can do very simple performance testing using the technique described here. I didn't read all of the code sample you gave but you can add those performance tests yourself and check out which operations take more time.

2: What I know of JavaScript and the browser is that changing the DOM is an expensive operation, you don't want to change the DOM too many times. What you can do instead is build up a set of changes and then apply all those changes with one DOM change. This may make your code less nice, but that's often the tradeoff you have when you want to have high performance.

Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response Niels Born. I used the DocumentFragment to prevent too much DOM access and changing and page re-renderings: with it the code accesses to the DOM just once per table.

Answer (score 2):

You should start by refactoring your code in multiples functions to make it a bit more readable. Make sure that you are separating DOM manipulation functions from data processing functions. Ideally, create a class and get those variables out of your function, this way you can access them with `this`.

Then, you should execute each function processing data in a [web worker](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp), so you're sure that your UI won't get blocked by the process. You won't be able to access `this` in a web worker so you will have to limit it to pure "input/output" operations.

You can also use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of homemade callbacks. It makes the code a bit more readable, and honestly easier to debug. You can do some cool stuff like :

```
this.processThis('hello').then((resultThis) => {
    this.processThat(resultThis).then((resultThat) => {
        this.displayUI(resultThat);
    }, (error) => {
        this.errorController.show(error); //processThat error
    });
}, (error) => {
    this.errorController.show(error); //processThis error
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guillaume and for the good luck wish. Web workers are great to prevent UI freezing. But in this specific case I'm not sure if it is a good thing implementing them: IMHO it's better that the user can't do anything into the program UI until it finishes loading data because if he does IMO a mess can happen. Nevertheless it could be interesting having a progress bar that shows the current status of the operation to the user: and if the timing of the operation goes over 5 secs in future, I'm already thinking to implement the progress bar.

Comment: About the separation of DOM manipulation functions from Data processing functions:

doesn't it mean to make more for loops that will take even more execution timing? Am I wrong?

Comment: Also you can't directly manipulate the DOM from inside a worker so I can't see how to use them in this specific case

Comment: Hey @willywonka! No you can't manipulate DOM from web worker, that's why I specified that it would be for the data processing functions ;-)

You don't need to make more loops while refactoring your code. You will just execute two functions in your loop instead of a one block of instructions.

Comment: "it's better that the user can't do anything into the program UI until it finishes loading data because if he does IMO a mess can happen"
I updated my answer to tell you about promises. You'll love them ;-)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I don't get it yet: my JavaScript knowledge is not as deep as you can see through the poor quality code I've posted. Nevertheless reading your answer and comments I got really curious: **How can I further optimize the code with your proposal for the part that executes data processing? And also what benefit can I get from the use of workers and promises?** I ask that because the pure data processing takes about 0.1 secs that IMHO could be fast enough. I tested that just commenting 3 rows:   **frag.appendChild(newEmbtyRow.cloneNode(true));
injectFragInTbody();**

Comment: JavaScript is (was) a single threaded language. It means that operations can't be executed in parallel of others operations. However a web worker is similar to a new thread, and I would say is an equivalent of threads in JavaScript. If you execute code in a web worker, your UI won't be interrupted by the processing of your datas, otherwise your UI might get frozen making it hard for you to show a loading indication to your user.

On another hand, promises allow you to replace callbacks, who are quickly turning your code into a mess. It basically works like a callback but is easier to read.

Comment: If you don't know what a callbacks are : they're basically a function that you give as an argument to a function you call so you can execute it inside the function you are calling. This technic allows you to execute code conditionally depending on what happens, typically error or success scenarios. Promises are making this easier. ;-)

Comment: OK so all this can improve the data processing that is 0.1 sec already (very short time IMHO) and the rest that is far longer than that (about 2.4 secs)? Let's suppose that we'll implement the worker and the promise that reduces the data processing to 0, IMO the main problem still remains because the DOM manipulation time is still too high at 2.4 secs that seems to me the biggest problem. Maybe I still don't get what you are trying to tell me, because of my deep inexperience, sorry for that: it is not you fault.

Comment: Well if you want to reduce the DOM manipulation time, then you should look into solution consisting in moving from the Shadow DOM to a Virtual DOM. 

You can use ReactJS fiber in order to get a way faster Virtual DOM.
You can use StencilJS to build a web component with it's own Virtual DOM. StencilJS is still an early stage project and you should not consider it for production yet.
You can see the performances for React here
https://claudiopro.github.io/react-fiber-vs-stack-demo/fiber.html and the performances for Stencil here
https://stencil-fiber-demo.firebaseapp.com/perf.html

Comment: I deduce from your last comment that i can't do any better with my code in vanilla js. Is my deduction correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. The best way to optimize DOM interractions is to use a virtual DOM, which you don’t want to spend time developing by yourself ;)

Comment: well... I think not.